# Arduino: Cannot move from one state to another (FastLED + Pixel Matrix)

Tags: arduino, fastled

I am trying to write a test code on Arduino with a LED Matrix I have built.
I wrote a couple of functions for animating graphics on the LED Matrix and wanted to change the animation at different integer 'parseInt' through Serial monitor.
However, I am able to get into either one of the 'states' but once I am in one of the states, I cannot transition to another when I send a different integer that supposedly activate its corresponding state.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?
The code is as shown below:

```
int state = 0;
void loop() {

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int mm = Serial.parseInt();
    if (mm == 1) {
      state = 1;
      while (state == 1) {
        animation1();

      }

    } else if (mm == 2) {
      state = 2;
      while (state == 2) {
        animation2();
        Serial.println(state);
      }} else if (mm == 3) {
        state=3;
        while (state ==3) {
        animation3();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried creating boolean variables, and tried also printing out the state the pixels is animating but it seems like once it enters one of the state it won't even read the new character sent via the serial monitor.

**just a note that solely putting the animation function inside if statement didn't work as it only displayed the 1st frame of the animation and not continuously... that's why I used the while loop**

Comment: In orde to "transit", you need to move from one state to another state after you done something, your code doesn't do that, it solely based on the input from the Serial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use while loop , it will cause an infinite loop there. So it will just stuck there indefinetely.

Try this

```
void loop() {

  while (Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
      int mm = Serial.parseInt();
      while(Serial.available() > 0)
      {
          Serial.read(); // This code to flush the new line character "/n"
      }

      while(Serial.available() == 0)
      {
           if (mm == 1) 
           {
              animation1();
           } 
           else if (mm == 2) 
           {
              animation2();
           } 
           else if (mm == 3) 
           {
              animation3();
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit : So we can add a while loop to check if there is no other output yet then just loop again and again. If there are new output stop the loop and print the new animation.

2nd Edit : This is a bug fix for the new line character that might intefer with the loop

3rd Edit : Cleanup code

Comment: The thing is, if I just put animation inside the if function, the LED animation only performs 1 frame and not continuous frame. Thats why I included the while loop.

Comment: is there a way where when entering the state, the animation performs all frames until the conditions holds false?

Comment: Yes sure can, I will edit the code now

Comment: omg.. I thought there was a problem with my animation code, but this worked! do u think i shud use the same logic when I am receiving characters via the Bluetooth protocol? I guess ill just change the int mm= Serial.parseInt to 'mm = Serial.read()'

Comment: yes sure, you can use the same logic as well.  Noted to handle the ' ```\n``` ' character if you want to use using serial.Read

Comment: do u mean to write \n character inside seria.Read ?

Comment: No, I mean that when you send the string from the serial monitor, actually the character '\n' will be automatically send by the serial monitor into Arduino as well. The real data that you want is without the '\n' character, so the '\n' character might cause you to fail the character comparison (the if else statement comparison). Btw you can try and play around first. This is just my suggestion. Read more here : https://forum.arduino.cc/t/help-with-serial-parseint/260948